# The expression when you want to correct something you just said

Tags: expressions

Do you use 'no' when you say something wrong and want to correct it?

## I got up at 10 PM, no no, 10AM!

If not, what do you use in informal context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would use one "no", not two. "No no" is what you say when you are rejecting something ("No no, we don't tolerate that kind of behaviour here.").

You could also say "No, wait" or "actually".

Comment: People say things different ways. If you are really annoyed at yourself,  you might say no twice. I can think of many ways to say this, including, I mean 10 a.m.